# Conditional statements with SSE

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm trying to do some calculations for my game, and I'm trying to calculate the distance between two points. Essentially, I'm using the equation of a circle to see if the points are inside of the radius that I define.

```
(x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2 <= r^2
```

My question is: how do I evaluate the conditional statement with SSE and interpret the results? So far I have this:

```
float distSqr4 = (pow(x4 - k->getPosition().x, 2) + pow(y4 - k->getPosition().y, 2));
float distSqr3 = (pow(x3 - k->getPosition().x, 2) + pow(y3 - k->getPosition().y, 2));
float distSqr2 = (pow(x2 - k->getPosition().x, 2) + pow(y2 - k->getPosition().y, 2));
float distSqr1 = (pow(x1 - k->getPosition().x, 2) + pow(y1 - k->getPosition().y, 2));

__m128 distances  = _mm_set_ps(distSqr1, distSqr2, distSqr3, distSqr4);
__m128 maxDistSqr = _mm_set1_ps(k->getMaxDistance() * k->getMaxDistance());
__m128 result     = _mm_cmple_ps(distances, maxDistSqr);
```

Once I get the result variable, I get lost. How do I use the result variable that I just got? My plan was, if the condition evaluated turned out to be true, to do some lighting calculations and then draw the pixel on the screen. How do I interpret true vs false in this case?

Any help towards the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand your question; you could, for instance, do `_mm_and_ps(distances, result)` to zero out the out of range values.

Comment: BTW, perhaps it is just for brevity, but why are you not doing the `(x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2` in SSE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My plan was, if the condition evaluated turned out to be true, to do some lighting calculations and then draw the pixel on the screen.

Then you really have little choice but to branch.

The big advantage of doing conditional tests using SSE is that it allows you to write *branchless* code, which can lead to massive speed improvements. But in your case, you pretty much have to branch because, if I'm understanding you correctly, you *never* want to output anything on the screen if the condition evaluated to false.

I mean, I guess you could do all of the calculations unconditionally (speculatively) and then just use the result of the conditional to twiddle bits in the pixel values, essentially causing you to draw off of the screen. That would give you branchless code, but it's pretty silly. There is a penalty for branch mispredictions, but it won't be anywhere near as expensive as all of the calculations and drawing code.

In other words, the parallelism you're using SIMD to exploit is exhausted once you have the final result. It's just a simple, scalar compare-and-branch. First you test whether the condition evaluated to true. If not, you'll jump *over* the code that does the lighting calculations and pixel-drawing. Otherwise, you'll just fall through to execute that code.

The tricky part is that the compiler won't let you use an `__m128` variable in a regular old `if` statement, so you need to "convert" `result` to an integer that you can use as the basis for a conditional. The easiest way to do that would be the `_mm_movemask_epi8` intrinsic.

So you would basically just do:

```
__m128 distances  = _mm_set_ps(distSqr1, distSqr2, distSqr3, distSqr4);
__m128 maxDistSqr = _mm_set1_ps(k->getMaxDistance() * k->getMaxDistance());
__m128 result     = _mm_cmple_ps(distances, maxDistSqr);

if (_mm_movemask_epi8(result) == (unsigned)-1)
{
    // All distances were less-than-or-equal-to the maximum, so
    // go ahead and calculate the lighting and draw the pixels.
    CalcLightingAndDraw(…);
}
```

This works because `_mm_cmple_ps` sets each packed double-word to all 1s if the comparison is true, or all 0s if the comparison is false. `_mm_movemask_epi8` then collapses that into an integer-sized mask and moves it to an integer value. You then can use that integer value in a normal conditional statement.

**Note:** With Clang and ICC, you can get away with passing a `__m128` value to the `_mm_movemask_epi8` intrinsic. On GCC, it insists upon a `__m128i` value. You can handle this with a cast: `_mm_movemask_epi8((__m128i)result)`.

Of course, I'm assuming here that you are only going to do the drawing if *all* of the distances are less-than-or-equal-to the maximum distance. If you want to treat each of the four distances *independently*, then you need to add more conditional tests on the mask:

```
__m128   distances  = _mm_set_ps(distSqr1, distSqr2, distSqr3, distSqr4);
__m128   maxDistSqr = _mm_set1_ps(k->getMaxDistance() * k->getMaxDistance());
__m128   result     = _mm_cmple_ps(distances, maxDistSqr);
unsigned condition  = _mm_movemask_epi8(result);

if (condition != 0)
{
    // One or more of the distances were less-than-or-equal-to the maximum,
    // so we have something to draw.

    if ((condition & 0x000F) != 0)
    {
        // distSqr1 was less-than-or-equal-to the maximum
        CalcLightingAndDraw(distSqr1);
    }
    if ((condition & 0x00F0) != 0)
    {
        // distSqr2 was less-than-or-equal-to the maximum
        CalcLightingAndDraw(distSqr2);
    }
    if ((condition & 0x0F00) != 0)
    {
        // distSqr3 was less-than-or-equal-to the maximum
        CalcLightingAndDraw(distSqr3);
    }
    if ((condition & 0xF000) != 0)
    {
        // distSqr4 was less-than-or-equal-to the maximum
        CalcLightingAndDraw(distSqr4);
    }
}
```

This won't result in very efficient code, since you have to do so many conditional test-and-branch operations. You might be able to continue parallelizing some of the lighting calculations *inside* of the main `if` block. I can't say for sure if this is workable, since I don't have enough details about your algorithm/design.

Otherwise, if you can't see any way to wring more parallelism out of the drawing code, the use of explicit SSE intrinsics isn't buying you much here. You were able to parallelize *one* comparison (`_mm_cmple_ps`), but the overhead of setting up for that comparison (`_mm_set_ps`, which will probably compile into `vinsertps` or `unpcklps`+`movlhps` instructions, assuming the inputs are already in XMM registers) will more than cancel out any trivial gains you might get. You'd arguably be just as well off writing the code like so:

```
float maxDistSqr = k->getMaxDistance() * k->getMaxDistance();
if (distSqr1 <= maxDistSqr)
{
    CalcLightingAndDraw(distSqr1);
}
if (distSqr2 <= maxDistSqr)
{
    CalcLightingAndDraw(distSqr2);
}
if (distSqr3 <= maxDistSqr)
{
    CalcLightingAndDraw(distSqr3);
}
if (distSqr4 <= maxDistSqr)
{
    CalcLightingAndDraw(distSqr4);
}
```

Comment: About the cast from `__m128` to `__m128i` that you mention GCC requires (MSVC requires it too), there intrinsics just for that. In this case it would be `_mm_castps_si128`. Kind of verbose but it is what it is. I think it is/was helpful to detect possible performance issues of switching between integer and float point instructions.